# Send HTML Email using PHP - Not working when using email.2015@gmail.com?

Tags: php, html, email

I am using this basic php code to send out a html email.

When i use `email@email.com` as a to address the script works.
However, when i try to use `email.2015@gmail.com` the script says:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '@' in /home/u925912002/public_html/send_email.php on line 3
```

My code:

```
<?php

$to = ‘email.2015@gmail.com’;

$subject = 'I need to show html'; 

$from ='example@example.com'; 

$body = '<p style=color:red;>This text should be red</p>';

ini_set("sendmail_from", $from);

$headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\nReply-To: " . $from . "";
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; 
if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {

  echo("<p>Sent</p>");
 } else {
  echo("<p>Error...</p>");
 }

?>
```

please can someone show me what i'm doing wrong. thanks

Comment: Why do your quotation marks around the email look different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your question recently closed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34106770/send-email-using-php-from-address-not-working

Try this:

`$headers .= "From: Your Name <$from>\r\n";`

and you can also add the [5th mail parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#example-3876):

`mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, '-finfo@userforum.com')`.

Works for me with these headers:

```
$from = "$name <$email>\r\n";
$to = "$username <$useremail>\r\n";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $name <$email>\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $name <$email>\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using Apostrophe(‘) instead of quotes(')

try this -

```
$to = 'email.2015@gmail.com';
```

instead of this -

```
$to = ‘email.2015@gmail.com’;
```