# php mail() cannot auto-send email to @hotmail.com, @outlook.com

Tags: php, email, spf

I use a very basic and simple `mail()` php function to automatically send email to the new users so that they can activate their account, which looks like this:

```
    $body = "Thank you for your registering at ". BASE_URL. ". To activate your account, please click on this link:\n\n";
    $body .= BASE_URL . 'activate.php?e=' . urlencode($e) . "&a=$a";
    mail($trimmed['email'], 'Registration Confirmation', $body, 'From: admin@hiteachers.com');
```

In which the `$trimmed['email']` is the email the new user uses to enter the website registration form after validation, and the `admin@hiteachers.com` is my **REAL** email address, which I use with Google apps (I followed the link `https://support.google.com/a/answer/33353?hl=en` (#2,3 and 4) to edit the MX records in my domain manager).

**Note** :
- I bought the domain and a shared linux server at Godaddy.

- I also consulted [PHP mail() function cannot send to hotmail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797626/php-mail-function-cannot-send-to-hotmail), and some other related links, but it didn't help.
- I also followed the link `https://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx` to troubleshoot the `SMTP Non-Delivery Report` by adding `hiteachers.com IN TXT "v=spf1 -all"` into the TXT records and waited for 48 hours, but no luck!
- I also added the TXT value `v=spf1 a mx -all` into my domain TXT records as per other stackoverflow users' suggestions, and waited for 48 hours, but no luck!
- I also added the `from` email address to the `safe contact list` of the recipient addresses at @hotmail.com, and @outlook.com, which i used for testing, but no luck!
- No email has been sent to @hotmail or @outlook inbox, even in the junk folder, and no bouce-back email either (because the recipient accounts are real).
- It works well with real **gmail** and **yahoo** email recipient addresses.
- I tried sending email directly from `admin@hiteachers.com` to the real recipient email address at outlook.com, it **stayed there** in the inbox (means that it accepts my admin@hiteachers.com address). However, when I viewed the message source, it says `This sender failed our fraud detection checks and may not be who they appear to be.`

Do you know what was wrong with it, or have you ever been in the same situation as mine? And the important part of my question is what I should do to **eliminate** the whole issue, please?

**UPDATED**

After adding the SPF and other required records, which you can take a look at here `http://mxtoolbox.com/` for the domain `hiteachers.com`, I received the report from `<email>noreply-dmarc-support@google.com</email>` like this, and all my testing auto-email to **@yahoo.com** and **@gmail.com** are going to spam folders, but not the inbox before:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<feedback>
  <report_metadata>
    <org_name>google.com</org_name>
    <email>noreply-dmarc-support@google.com</email>
    <extra_contact_info>https://support.google.com/a/answer/2466580</extra_contact_info>
    <report_id>10844434555482221094</report_id>
    <date_range>
      <begin>1458172800</begin>
      <end>1458259199</end>
</date_range>
  </report_metadata>
  <policy_published>
    <domain>hiteachers.com</domain>
    <adkim>r</adkim>
    <aspf>r</aspf>
    <p>quarantine</p>
    <sp>quarantine</sp>
    <pct>100</pct>
  </policy_published>
  <record>
    <row>
      <count>1</count>
      <policy_evaluated>
        <disposition>quarantine</disposition>
        <dkim>fail</dkim>
        <spf>fail</spf>
      </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    <identifiers>
      <header_from>hiteachers.com</header_from>
    </identifiers>
    <auth_results>
      <spf>
        <domain>xxxxxxxxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx.secureserver.net</domain>
        <result>none</result>
      </spf>
    </auth_results>
  </record>
</feedback>
```

Comment: Try this structure [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34107379/5455207)

Comment: which OS you were using ? If linux try this command and check once: sudo apt-get install sendmail      Just assuming

Comment: Why is your SPF record empty?

Comment: @tadman: You can take a look at my SPF records here `http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3ahiteachers.com&run=toolpage#` and also the MX records, DKIM records, and **dmarc** too.

Comment: The new issue just arisen now is that all auto-emails to the testing **yahoo.com* and **gmail.com** are going spam folders. I just received the report from `<email>noreply-dmarc-support@google.com</email>`, which I added in the **UPDATED**. can you help?

Comment: Anyone can help with my case? thanks

Comment: Your setup only fits for *Gmail for Work*, *Google Apps for Work* or *Google Apps free (legacy)*. If you don't use those products as a mail gateway, then your setup is wrong. If you only want to send mails locally without Google beeing your Gateway, then your setup is wrong. The way you want to route your mails is not clear to me.

Comment: Hi all, it works for me now after altering the SPF records from `v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all` to `v=spf1 a include:_spf.google.com ~all`

Comment: You still have something set up wrong, all you did was change it from `v=spf1 a mx -all` to `v=spf1 a ~all` the `include:_spf.google.com` is pointless, since you're not using gmail to send with in this instance.  So what I think happened is you went from "Fail" to "SoftFail" by changing the `-` to `~` . You should test you SPF using [mailtest](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/emailauthentication/) to make sure you're not really failing SPF, I have a feeling you still are.

Comment: @henry : all outgoing emails to `@hotmail.com` and `@outlook.com` are successful, though it's still going into their Junk boxes anyway. To me, it's still better than NONE as before. The `mailtest` you suggested is not free anyway!

Comment: @Phong - Since it's going to junk mail in hotmail, can you post the headers from hotmail, it has a anti-spam line that tells you why it's being filtered into junk. Also some basic tests are free in mailtest like DKIM, SPF, ETC and they have a summary on top that gives you an idea of how many issues you might have. The ability to send mail is priceless in my opinion.